# How Can I mount shared drive in Python with no root?

Tags: python, linux, share, root, drive

I am trying to mount a shared drive by using **os.system()** in python.
The problem is, that the installed linux version has no sudo command. Installing a sudo-package has failed.
When using the command su, I am getting an error that it must be used with **suid**.
I can't **chmod +s** because I have no root.

Any ideas? Mods? Or Buffer Overflow is the only solution here? =)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/, since it has little to do with python or programming, and more with with the specifics of the linux `mount` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mount without root privileges (except in some circumstances, see below.) If you have no privileges on that machine, you have to ask the administrator.

What an *administrator* can do is insert certain mount points into `/etc/fstab` and mark them `user`. An administrator could also install `sudo` for you and allow you to execute `sudo mount`.

Python has no way (and shouldn't have a way) to circumvent these basic security features.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought. The thing is that the linux OS is on hardware and needs some workaround because support does not answer ;)

I will check that fuse and come back if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fuse: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

It depends on what exactly you want to mount whether there is a fuse-module which is capable of doing so.

And of course it has to be installed.